# Writing a Discord bot, getting an error when new member joins

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to build a Discord bot as a fun way to get a better grasp of Python and learn a thing or two about using APIs.

I want to make my bot to mention and message new members when they join the server (message in server, not dm).

My code for that goes like this:

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(self, member):
    ment = member.mention
    await self.client.get_channel(my channels id goes here).send(f"{ment} welcome blabla text...")
    print(f"{member} welcome blabla text...")
```

However, when a new member joins I get this error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_member_join
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\folder\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: on_member_join() missing 1 required positional argument: 'member'
```

I see the issue is with member object but I can't figure out what exactly.

Comment: Did you try omitting the `self` parameter in the function definition?

Comment: I did and it finally works! Thank you @mkrieger1. However I am baffled, I see on Reddit that another person has used the above code with `self` parameter and their code works.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make it like this

member: discord.Member

Also use {user.mention} instead of member in the last line.